# Sharepoint Pop Up on an ENtry

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a survey in Sharepoint 2010 
I have one question which asks for Team name. 
What i want is that whenever a user selects this question i.e Team -Name, i want that some kind of Pop up comes up and asks the user to enter the Name of members of that team.
Is it possible to do so?
Would be great if you can help?

Answer (score 1):

i think this might be simple ;)

once you have made your survey you can edit the aspx file here:

/lists/survey/NewForm.aspx

open newForm.aspx and add some JS (javascript) at the top. Give the control that you want an onlick event that calls the JS method :) Bingo!

link below shows how to add JS to aspx file :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

once you have made the changes reinsert back the file overwriting the origional!

as an example someone has done the JS as an example in an aspx showing a popup that shows a website and its similar to your needs, obviously not the same ;)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>PopUp Window</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(url) {
var width = 300;
var height = 200;
var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
params += ', toolbar=no';
params += ', menubar=no';
params += ', resizable=yes';
params += ', directories=no';
params += ', scrollbars=no';
params += ', status=no';
params += ', location=no';
newwin = window.open(url, 'd', params);
if (window.focus) 
{
    newwin.focus() 
}
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('http://www.c-sharpcorner.com')">Click Here</a> </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

If you want to show some message or some content in popup window then you can give the xml file path like as follows:

<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('XMLFile.xml')">Click Here</a>
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4070/

as you can see you have the JS at the top and below in the control onclick you have the JS calling popup function in JS. Instead of `window.open(url, 'd', params);` you need to add a lable and texbox and do what you want with the value :)